# How Many Staircases

Tags: code-golf, sequence, code-challenge, recursion

#### Problem

You're a staircase engineer on a house and realize you only have **`n` rectangles to create a staircase**. So you are tasked with finding the number of ways to use `n` rectangles to tile a stairstep shape for the architects.

Your task is to write a program that takes a **non-negative integer `n`** as input and calculates the **number of ways a staircase can be made with `n` rectangles**.

[Image credit](https://www.robertdickau.com/catalan.html#step)

### Examples

**2** rectangles, **2** ways:

[image]

**3** rectangles, **5** ways:

[image]

**4** rectangles, **14** ways:

[image]

**5** rectangles, **42** ways:

[image]

**6** rectangles, **132** ways:

[image]

### Input

- `n` is a non-negative integer. (2 ≤ `n` ≤ 15)

### Test Cases

```yaml
Input: 2    Output: 2
Input: 5    Output: 42
Input: 8    Output: 1430
Input: 12   Output: 208012
Input: 14   Output: 2674440
```

#### Hint:

> **OEIS A000108**

> [image]

**Shortest Code Wins**